# parsing string with problematic delimiter '\'

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, file, io

I know there are many questions and solutions on this subject, but the problem is that the string which I want to parse is a path to file which is written with back slashes, and the compiler can't read it, so all the other posts on this subject didn't help me.

I'm writing an MFC dialog based application on Visual Studio 2017, in C++.

In my dialog I want to enable the user to open the file explorer by pressing a button, and navigating to specific file. When he chooses the file I want to save the path for later so I'll be able to open this file and write into it. this is how it looks:

[image]

when the user presses `Save To File` button, the file explorer opens, and he can navigate to the desired file. this is the code I've written to response to the click on `Save To File` button:

```
void CEditableListControlDlg::OnBnClickedButton3() {
    OPENFILENAME file;

    TCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH] = _T("");

    SecureZeroMemory(&file, sizeof(file));

    file.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    file.hwndOwner = NULL;
    file.lpstrFilter = NULL;
    file.lpstrFile = szFileName;
    file.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    file.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
    file.lpstrDefExt = "txt";

    GetSaveFileName(&file);
}
```

I've printed the string that is saved in `file.lpstrFile` and it was correct, so I thought I have the path. the problem is that the path is saved in a format which uses back slashes `C:\Users\path\to\file.txt` and sometimes the compiler thinks that `\User` for example is the \U character, so when late on I try to open the file, it won't open.

the path looks like this:

[image]

I want to parse the string and rebuild the path using forward slashes, but I'm having trouble with it, since the compiler don't understand that `C:\Users\Path\To\File.txt` is a string and won't let me access it. I've tried using the following code for example:

```
    std::string path = file.lpstrFile; // path to file using back slashes saved here
    std::string delimiter = "\"";
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token, FileName("");
    while ((pos = path.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = path.substr(0, pos);
        if (FileName == "") FileName = token;
        else FileName = FileName + '/' + token;
        path.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
```

the code works but not on this delimiter (I've tried switching the delimiter to `,` and parse `C:,Users,Path,To,File.txt` and it worked)

How can I transform this string `C:\Users\Path\To\File.txt` into this `C:/Users/Path/To/File.txt` ?

Thank you.

Comment: You are aware that to represent a single backslash, you'll need to escape it as  a doubled backslash, are you? Knowing this it should be fairly easy to replace the characters in the path representation.

Comment: You seem to be using `"` as delimiter, not \.

Comment: Did you try using backslash as a delimeter?

Comment: I think you are confusing the representation of strings in C++ (which interpret backslashed characters specially) with the run-time string value (where a backslash is just a backslash). I promise you that the C++ standard library on Windows can deal with backslashed paths. Can you edit your question with an example of where eg opening a file using `file.lpstrFile` fails?

Comment: thank you everyone, I feel so stupid to miss it... as @KonardRudolph have mentioned, I used the wrong delimiter. It should be \\ and not \"